# AVD not booting after Android Studio update

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-update-sdk

My AVDs are no longer booting after I installed a 921MB update released these days. I don't exactly remember the entity of the update (maybe API/SDK revision), I'm using Android Studio 2.3 build AI-162.4069837 with API 25 revision 3 (I think this last thing is the actual update) on Debian.

When I start up the AVD it just keeps a black screen and never completes booting. The log shows this error just after it starts booting the AVD:

```
1292-1328/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/system_ce/0: No such file or directory
1292-1328/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/misc_ce/0: No such file or directory
1292-1328/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/media/0: No such file or directory
```

It's like there is no file system initalized.

After that I keep getting a loop of errors, which I pasted at https://pastebin.com/cbk9T8KR.

Anybody else having troubles? Any ideas on how to get the VM working again?

Comment: I've tried many things: deleting the .android folder, deleting and removing the AVDs with different architecture, I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Comment: Glad to hear somebody else is in my condition...

Comment: did you try starting it from CLI

Comment: no difference except I didn't have the Android monitor to see the log, however I found a solution I've just posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a temporary solution hoping they'll fix the bug. You should open config.ini inside .android/AVD/[AVD name]/ and set

```
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.gpu.mode=swiftshader
```

and the VM got back to work properly.

Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36905888

Answer (score 0):

for all Windows Users the config.ini is in

C:\Users\yourname.android\avd\yourdevicename.avd/config.ini

and the entries

hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.gpu.mode=auto

exist already. But the change of hw.gpu.mode to "swiftshader" works perfectly.