# Android Emulator blank screen after launching

Tags: android, emulation, qemu

1. I have my SDK in a separate folder in D:/Drive.
2. I have the already downloaded SDK, and system image for android 25
3. I am able to create the emulator and launch the emulator, but after launching it just gives nothing but a blank screen.

I am using Windows 10, emulator specification is very normal (x86,512Mb RAM). 
Tried by enabling and disabling "Use HOST GPU".

I am getting a warning in the launch window. 
1. Failed to process emu-update-last-check.ini file

Comment: one more error/warning while launching the emulator is 
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!

Comment: Have you tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44812321/avd-not-booting-after-android-studio-update?

Comment: @J-rooft i tried it. the problem is with my display driver i guess. will update the display driver to intel display driver and will update you on the same.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the display driver. I had the default microsoft driver. 
once i installed "Intel HD graphics Driver" it worked perfectly