# Android error : E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/system_ce/0: No such file or directory

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've an android app I'm working on in the Android Studio. The app was working fine then all of a sudden gave me an error as it tried to open my emulator. Here it is from the logcat:

> 07-05 23:40:23.977 1313-1356/? E/vold: Failed to chmod
>   /data/system_ce/0: No such file or directory.

I'm just learning Android. To my knowledge, I didn't intentionally change anything in the app (Java, XML, etc). I'm lost on how to solve this. I do work on it between two laptops so I don't know if doing that is causing me issue. Up to this point, it has not.

thanks.

Comment: I have not faced this issue before.. but this might help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44842514/7316675

Comment: @ChaiBiskut this change doesn't work, I get the same problem

Comment: I too got this error and solved when duplicating the same project